# How to optimize nested for-loop in Fortran when the order of the loop matters?

Tags: fortran, openmp, gfortran

I have a relatively simple subroutine where it is stored the number of occurrence of the number 2 in an array. I have two 2D arrays geno_pro(2000, 50000) and geno_par(100000, 50000). I need to compare each row from geno_pro with each row from geno_par, and count how many numbers 2 it has.

```
  subroutine ptoh(oh_ped, oh_cnt, m, npro, npar)
    use omp_lib
    implicit none
    integer :: par,pro,npar,npro,m,i,i_M,i_F,total_snp,effective
    integer :: geno_par(npar,m),geno_pro(npar,m),oh_po(npar),sex(npar),sex_par(npar)
    integer :: progeny_snp(m),parent_snp(m),oh_cnt(npro,4)
    character*20 :: parent(npar),progeny(npro),bird_par(npar),oh_ped(npro,3)
    character(len=m) :: snp
    ! Read parents' id, gender and genotypes
    open(unit=100, file="parents.txt", status='old', action='read')
    !$omp parallel do private(i,snp) shared(geno_par,parent,sex,npar,m)
    do i=1,npar
      read(100,*) parent(i), sex(i), snp
      read(snp,'(*(i1))') geno_par(i,1:m)
    end do
    !$omp end parallel do
    close(unit=100)
    ! Read progeny's id and genotypes 
    open(unit=200, file="progeny.txt", status='old', action='read')
    !$omp parallel do private(i,snp) shared(geno_pro,progeny,npro,m)
    do i=1,npro
      read(200,*) progeny(i), snp
      read(snp,'(*(i1))') geno_pro(i,1:m)
    end do
    !$omp end parallel do
    close(unit=200)
    ! Count OH
    !$omp parallel do private(pro,par,progeny_snp,parent_snp,i_M,i_F) &
    !$omp private(bird_par,sex_par,oh_po,total_snp,effective) &
    !$omp shared(m,npro,npar,geno_pro,geno_par,parent,sex,oh_ped,oh_cnt)
    do pro=1,npro
      progeny_snp = geno_pro(pro,1:m)
      total_snp = count(progeny_snp .ge. 0)
      effective = count(progeny_snp .le. 2)
      do par=1,npar
        parent_snp = geno_par(par,1:m)
        bird_par(par) = parent(par)
        sex_par(par) = sex(par)
        oh_po(par) = count(abs(progeny_snp - parent_snp) .eq. 2)
      end do
      i_M = minloc(oh_po, dim=1, mask=(sex_par .eq. 1))
      i_F = minloc(oh_po, dim=1, mask=(sex_par .eq. 2))
      oh_ped(pro,1:3) = (/progeny(pro),bird_par(i_M),bird_par(i_F)/)
      oh_cnt(pro,1:4) = (/total_snp,effective,oh_po(i_M),oh_po(i_F)/)
    end do
    !$omp end parallel do
  end subroutine ptoh
```

This is the part the I am struggling to optimize.

```
    do pro=1,npro
      progeny_snp = geno_pro(pro,1:m)
      total_snp = count(progeny_snp .ge. 0)
      effective = count(progeny_snp .le. 2)
      do par=1,npar
        parent_snp = geno_par(par,1:m)
        bird_par(par) = parent(par)
        sex_par(par) = sex(par)
        oh_po(par) = count(abs(progeny_snp - parent_snp) .eq. 2)
      end do
      i_M = minloc(oh_po, dim=1, mask=(sex_par .eq. 1))
      i_F = minloc(oh_po, dim=1, mask=(sex_par .eq. 2))
      oh_ped(pro,1:3) = (/progeny(pro),bird_par(i_M),bird_par(i_F)/)
      oh_cnt(pro,1:4) = (/total_snp,effective,oh_po(i_M),oh_po(i_F)/)
    end do
```

Even using OpenMP it is still slow. I wonder if there is a better way to speed it up. Does anyone has an idea about how to improve it? Thank you.

Comment: All your array accesses are in the wrong order - your innermost loops access go down the ast dimension when best performance will be with them going down the first. Swapping the order of dimensions of the arrays will probably  give you an order of magnitude roughly in performance.  To get substantially more I suspect your algorithm will have to be improved.

Comment: As @Ian Bush pointed out, Fortran arrays are stored in column-major order `array(i,j,k)` opposed to C arrays which are in row-major order: `array[k][j][i]`. E.g: `oh_ped(pro,1:3)` --> `oh_ped(1:3,pro)`. For more info see [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4940/z400091044d0/), [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) or [post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order).

Comment: It helped a little bit. I think I will rewrite the algorithm. Thanks.